# Storing histogram data as a string of counts in bin in a dat file in Python?

Tags: python, histogram, saving-data

I am using a script to animate the oscillations of particle distributions that is used for data in a certain format.

I want to save my histogram plot as a string of data as a .dat file in the following form:

```
10 -1 1 10
0.1 0 0 1 2 4 7 3 2 1 0
0.2 0 1 1 3 4 8 2 2 0 0 
etc
```

where the numbers in the first line are the number of data points, lowest boundary, highest boundary of sampling, number of bins respectively.

The later lines as one can see is the actual data with 11 numbers the first of which is the time step and the the rest 10 numbers are number of counts in each bin for the distribution at that time. Also, note each different line is the date for a separate distribution (since it is at a later time)
so I will probably need a `f.write(\n)` somewhere.

If let's say I have a histogram from the command:

```
count,bins,ignored=plt.hist(distribution,bins,density=True)
```

where  `distribution` is an array which contains the positions of the particles.

How do I now save it in a ,dat file in the format above?

In essence, how do I get the count in the bins for the histogram from the above command?

**Edit:**

So, I know now how to get the counts in a bin.

After using,

`hist,edge=np.histogram(test_,bins=10)`

I get the data as follows:   `7  114  562 1652 2876 2864 1392  449   77    7`

If my time step is `0.1` how do I write this whole thing as above in a .dat file.

I have tried

```
  with open('up.dat', 'w') as f:

   f.writelines(str(hist))
```

but that gives a dat file with content `[   7  114  562 1652 2876 2864 1392  449   77    7]`